# AngularJS - Docs say cannot nest ng-app - I can fine...why? Thoughts?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

https://jsbin.com/pewimofija/1/edit?html,js,output

I was just sort of messing around trying to see about having multiple nested ng-apps, in order to help modularize an application a little easier.  I was able to nest multiple ng-apps without manually bootstrapping.  If I remove any dependencies, the functionality breaks, but with the dependencies correct, it works.  Obviously in real practice I would not have a button as an individula ng-app, but just testing things out.  I was thinking this could help modularize without having to create complex directives, which have a bit of a learning curve.

Please see my JsBin.

Comment: Your other `ng-app` attributes aren't doing anything.  Your code is working because the other modules are being loaded when mainApp is bootstrapped, making them available when you use `ng-controller`

Comment: I see...so it's fine to have as many angular.modules as you want, but the app will only bootstrap to the first ng-app it finds and ignores the others?

Comment: Thanks by the way for taking the time to answer!